# How to check for collisions between objects with the same script?

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection, physics

I am creating a game where there would be two objects instantiated. Each one has a script (to check for collisions), a `Rigidbody2D` component and a `Collider2D` of course.

The thing is that I want to call a function whenever the two objects collide each other, but when those two objects collide, the function is called **twice** (once from object1, and once from object2) but I want it to be called **once**.

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this is to check the instance ID, and let the object with the lower ID "own" the collision.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {

    if (collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out ThisScript otherscript)) {
        // Two of the same script colliding.

        if (gameObject.GetInstanceId() > collision.gameObject.GetInstanceId())
            return; // I have the higher ID — abort!

        // Put code to call only once in
        // same-script collisions here.
    }
}
```